# React Hooks useState() with an Array of Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

while I am creating new "Todo" and modifying the fields are no problem my issue is receiving back the child data when I click the "show all objects" button.

Here is a code example to illustrate my issue:

```js
const CompoOne = () =>{
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState("")
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState("")

  const addTodo = () => setTodos(
     [...todos, { a: "Title", b: "subTitle", c: "content"}]
  )

  return (
        <>
          <InputText
            value={subject}
            setValue={setSubject}
            label="subject field"
          />
          <InputText
            value={priority}
            setValue={setPriority}
            label="priority field"
          />
          <hr />
          <h2>Todo:</h2>
          <hr />
          <button
            onClick={()=>addTodo()}
          >
            add a todo
          </button>
          <>
            {setTodos.map((el,i)=>(
                <CompoTwo
                  todo={el}
                  setTodos={setTodos}
                  todos={todos}
                  key={i}
                />
            )}
          </>

          <button
            onClick={()=>console.log(todos)}
          >
            show all objects
          </button>
        </>
  )
}


const compoTwo = ({ todo, todos, setTodos }) =>{
  const [a, setA] = useState("")
  const [b, setB] = useState("")
  const [c, setC] = useState("")

  const handleChange = (e) =>{
    const {name, value} = e.target
    setTodos((prevState)=>{
      //I would like to update the inside the prevState instance
      const updatedArray = // something like [...prevState, [name]:value]
      // return updatedArray
    })
  }

  return(
    <>
          <InputText
            value={a}
            name="a"
            onChange={(e)=>setA(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            label="field A"
          />
          <InputText
            value={b}
            name="b"
            onChange={(e)=>setB(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            label="field B"
          />
          <InputText
            value={c}
            name="c"
            onChange={(e)=>setC(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            label="field C"
          />
    </>
  )
}
```

if I click twice on the "add a Todo" button and change one of the field's values, I will still get the default value

```js
[
  {a: "Title", b: "subTitle", c:"content"},
  {a: "Title", b: "subTitle", c:"content"},
]
```

and my purpose would be to get the updated value of the child component.

if you got any idea...

here is the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-water-h79dis?file=/src/App.js) link to try and play

thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder if your code can be misunderstood because of the component and variable naming. It think `CompoOne` is a `TodoList` and `CompoTwo` a `TodoItem` component? In `CompoOne` you specify props `a`, `b` and `c`, but you have some states `subject` and `priority` are they the same? What about the third value? In your `CompoOne` you try to iterate over the setter function with `setTodos.map` which will not work I think you want to iterate over your todos?

Comment: I just simplified the real issue to the thing I need, the real case is much more complicated, as I do not want to put the 400 lines of code, I create this simple and basic code example with what the thing I block with and that I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this and hope it may help you for **compoTwo**.

> Note: You can also set the todo prop value as the initial value of useState.

```
const compoTwo = ({ todo, todos, setTodos }) =>{
  const [a, setA] = useState("")
  const [b, setB] = useState("")
  const [c, setC] = useState("")

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setTodos((prevState) => {
      const temp = [...prevState];
      const find = temp.find((res) => res.id === todo.id);
      if (find) {
        find[name] = value;
        return temp;
      } else {
        return prevState;
      }
    });
  };

  return(
    <>
          <InputText
            value={a}
            name="a"
            onChange={(e)=>setA(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            label="field A"
          />
          <InputText
            value={b}
            name="b"
            onChange={(e)=>setB(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            label="field B"
          />
          <InputText
            value={c}
            name="c"
            onChange={(e)=>setC(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            label="field C"
          />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have something wrong when set initials value for UseState and SetTodos, you can refer to the code below:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
{ a: 'Title', b: 'subTitle', c: 'content' },
{ a: 'Title', b: 'subTitle', c: 'content' }
]);
const addTodo = (todo) => {
 setTodos([...todos, todo]);
};
```

Comment: How I start the `[todos, setTodos]` isn't the matter. both are working fine.

the difference would be in the view,
with your code

already 2 components exist, with mine nothing exist until you click the button.

Comment: @Farid212 how the state is initialized isn't the point here. The point is how the `addTodo` function is implemented. In your code you always add the static strings `{ a: "Title", b: "subTitle", c: "content"}` to your array but you have to pass the actual values.